# Error when trying to spawn a thread that opens a tcp connection

Tags: rust

```
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

use std::error::Error;

use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::io;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead, FramedWrite};


use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    let stdin = FramedRead::new(io::stdin(), BytesCodec::new());
    let stdin = stdin.map(|i| i.map(|bytes| bytes.freeze()));
    let stdout = FramedWrite::new(io::stdout(), BytesCodec::new());

    let addr: SocketAddr = ...

    tokio::spawn(async move {
       tcp::connect(&addr, stdin, stdout, rx_client_out).await?;
    });   
 

    Ok(())
}
```

It seems the error is because of the return type of the function that makes the tcp connection, i.e. the `Box<dyn Error>`

I'm not sure how to fix this, was hoping someone can explain it.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): FromResidual<Result<Infallible, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>` is not satisfied
  --> service/src/bin/abcd.rs:43:29
   |
43 |       tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  _____________________________-
44 | |         tcp::connect(&addr, stdin, stdout, rx_client_out).await?;
45 | |     });
   | |     ^
   | |     |
   | |_____the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>` is not implemented for `()`
```

The function outline looks like this:

```
mod tcp {
    use bytes::Bytes;
    use futures::{future, Sink, SinkExt, Stream, StreamExt};
    use std::{error::Error, io, net::SocketAddr};
    use tokio::net::TcpStream;
    use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead, FramedWrite};

    use crate::das_client;

    pub async fn connect(
        addr: &SocketAddr,
        mut stdin: impl Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, io::Error>> + Unpin,
        mut stdout: impl Sink<Bytes, Error = io::Error> + Unpin,
        inbound_das_client: tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<das_client::Commands>
    ) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
       
        /// ...

        match future::join(sink.send_all(&mut stdin), stdout.send_all(&mut stream)).await {
            (Err(e), _) | (_, Err(e)) => Err(e.into()),
            _ => Ok(()),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `?` operator inside an async block which is returning `()`. The compiler is complaining because it cannot propagate the error from `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` to `()`. To fix this you could simply call `.unwrap()` or `.expect()` since you're not handling the error even if you propagate it. So,

```rust
tokio::spawn(async move {
    tcp::connect(&addr, stdin, stdout, rx_client_out).await.expect("Something went wrong with tcp connection");
});
```

Comment: How do you let the block return the result then, assuming you wanted to?  That's not exactly the question, but is the first thing that occurs to me, as it's fully possible I'd want that kind of thing from an async task.

Comment: @KevinAnderson `tcp::connect()` returns `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` and after applying `?` it returns either `()` or will propagate the error to its return type. Since you are not returning anything, rust thinks that the return type of that block is `()` thus leading to the problem of not being able to to propagate the error. You can return a `Result` variant in the end to signify that the block returns `Result<T, E>` but you will have to specify its generic types, which in your case will be `Ok::<(), Box<dyn Error>>(())`. Then you can call `?`. Hope this helps

Comment: That makes sense, I just thought that the `?` would be enough for the compiler to see "oh if that's there, then the return type _has_ to be a `Result` type" instead of erroring.  And then also enforce `Ok()` at the end.  Well I guess talking through it shows how it has to make the call one way or the other, which to error on?  I think I'd prefer it to yell at me about the end, and let me use `?` but I can see somebody making the opposite call.  Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the `Result` but that you're trying to call an `async` task from a synchonous thread.

You're using `tokio`, so look into [`tokio::task::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html) to make the new *task* you are making, which isn't necessarily a new thread.  I'd also recommend looking into the [tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial).

Comment: I meant to createa tokio spawn sorry, I am still getting an error like before (I edited my question above)